# How to collect scattered ideas on various topics in to a blog post/ writing article?

Tags: blog, process

I try to write on various Q&A sites, but now I am thinking about having my own blog website. The main thing is that I don't know exactly what my niche topics would be for blogs. I write on various scattered topics. Among those: how to choose one as a specialized blog topic niche for my website?

How can I manage my thoughts on different topics into one place? And based on it I have to choose my blog area of writings.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As [a long-time blogger](http://popculturephilosopher.com), I can say from experience: **It's much harder to get any traction with an audience if you don't have a specific topic or theme**.  But it depends on what your goals for the blog are.  If your primary aim is to express yourself, and to have a place to keep your writing skills sharp, then it's okay for your blog to reflect that.  But if you're focused on building an audience, your best bet is to find an under-served niche and fill it.  It's like choosing a restaurant for dinner.  Some restaurants thrive on doing well at a wide variety of cuisines.  But most restaurants specialize.  People come to them when they want something specific.

So, to summarize, one approach to blogging is more personal and expressive, the other is more business-minded and goal-oriented.  **If you just want a personal blog, there's no right or wrong answer as to how to set it up**.  If your goal is to build an audience, then you should do market research, and find out what people want that they aren't getting.

I think most of us, myself included, get in trouble when **we think one blog is going to excel at BOTH aims**, personal expression and audience-building.  I won't say it never happens, but you have to an an extraordinarily compelling voice if you're going to attract people to sign on to your own meandering personal journey.

Answer (score 1):

There's actually a simple solution to this:
Do a meta-blog-post. I've seen such articles in magazins and newspapers from time to time, when a writer doesn't write on his typical topic, but about how his thought process went when he writes his articles. Using this method, you can combine several thoughts you had and add why you choose to give this topic more space and the other topic less.

I hope I didn't misunderstand your question, English is not my first language.

Answer (score 1):

You don't necessarily *need* to focus on one topic. Many blogs are about one specific topic and use that to attract their readers, but there are also other types or blogs that are more focused on you as the author. For example because you have an interested writing style or are good at picking up trends.

If you really want to focus on one specific topic you should write a few posts and see whether you can find a common denominator to all of them. Typically it will be something you are interested in doing on a regular basis anyway. For example if you are a programmer you might regularly check out new programming language and then write blog posts about them - What features do the languages have? How do they compare to each other? What do you like and dislike about them? What do you anticipate for them for the near and far future?

As you can see there are different things that you can write about even if it's just one such little topic.

You might also be interested in the previous questions [Mixing topics in a blog](https://writing.stackexchange.com/q/3015/23159) and [becoming better blogger when I write about diverse topics](https://writing.stackexchange.com/q/9028/23159) here on Writing.SE.